# Query on how to fetch other fields in MySQL while using distinct

Tags: mysql

I have set up a SQL query to get the distinct fields.

```
select distinct col1, col2 
from table 
where col7="match"
```

On the above condition, I also need to append the value of `col2` and `col3`. These need not be unique. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` before the columns means `distinct for all`, if you want achieve this you can use `group by` :

```
select col1, col2 , col3, col7
from table 
group by col1
having col7="match"
```

Comment: why do you use **HAVING** and not **WHERE**

Comment: I tried what you mentioned above, However i get an error unkown column 'col7' in 'having clause'

Comment: Using a where, i get an error. It is a syntax error

Comment: @Jigar sorry, you must include col7 which used in having clause in selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

ok so after a little research i figured it out. distinct like mentioned gives distinct for all.

So no point using, 
select distinct col1, col2, col3 
from table 
where col7="match"

This would end up giving us unique combination for col1, col2 and col3. So instead here is the solution that worked for me using group by.

select col1, col2, col3, col7 from table where col7="match" group by col1, col2